# Fabric8: How to manage microservices external resources like RDBMS/Nosql/Middelwares?

Tags: fabric8

I have looked at the documentation of fabric8 but I did not found answers for these questions:
1. How external resources like RDBMS/Nosql/Middelwares used by a microservice app should be installed for the different stages : I guess that using a docker-compose file referencing the docker images for a db for example is not sufficient or should it be manually.

2. How could I monitor/admin those resources?

An example of an app microservice using an external resources would be very helpful.

Comment: Do you refer to the `fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin` for plain Docker usage or the `fabric8/fabric8-maven-plugin` for building for a Kubernetes and/or OpenShift cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to the [fabric8-maven-plugin](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-maven-plugin) for creating Kubernetes and OpenShift resource descriptors, you can specify so called *resource fragments* in the `src/main/fabric8` which refers your external services and which will be picked up with `mvn fabric8:resource`.

The GitHub organisation https://github.com/fabric8-quickstarts contains a lot of examples, unfortunately not one which directly picks up an external service.

Another source of examples is https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-devops which contains tons of external application packaged with fabric8-maven-plugin (e.g. [fluentd](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-devops/tree/master/fluentd)).

The documentation also contains a section on [resource fragments](https://maven.fabric8.io/#resource-fragments) which you can put in `src/main/fabric8`